Oracle Apex Filter Option Under the Actions Menu for an Interactive Report
I apologize in advance if this question is vague or confusing.
In Oracle Apex for the Filter options under the Actions menu for an Interactive Report for a date column, is there a way to change the order when picking a specific time. (i.e HR MI PM instead of PM MI HR). The format mask for this date column is MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI PM. Please see the image below for what's circled in red. I have checked the in the builder under attributes but there is no options to modify. Moreover, I am not sure if there is Javascript solution. Please let me know there is solution to this issue. Thanks.
Image 1
I tried various options in the application builder. I also checked in inspect element and found the below code snippet but I am not sure if it can be changed.
Image 2
